# Is there a way to access datetime constants in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, datetime, kohana, constants, kohana-3

Before I used a framework, I'd often define things like so (so my code makes more sense to read)

```
define('MINUTE', 60);
define('HOUR', MINUTE * 60); // etc
```

Is anything like this built into Kohana 3, or should I specify this myself (perhaps in bootstrap.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kohana 3 static class `Date` gives you access to these constants. [View source](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/date.php#L12).

Usage as follows

```
$week = Date::WEEK;
$year = Date::YEAR; // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Kohana has a few [date helpers](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/date) but nothing for your specific need.  Just declare it yourself!